# Add 30 seconds more to the timer

Tags: flutter

Hello I am doing a flutter app , and I want to use a button to add 30s more to the time when it's pressed. The timer starts with 60 seconds , but I want the user to be able to add 30 seconds more if he needs . I only find at the controller(of time) the options like: reverse() , reset() , resync() but nothing to add the time. This is what I used in the beginning of the code ( I will post only some paths because the code is very big)

```
class _CountDownTimerState extends State<CountDownTimer>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;

  String get timerString {
    Duration duration = controller.duration * controller.value;
    return '${duration.inMinutes}:${(duration.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
 controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 60),
    );
  }
```

and this is how I write my code for the button with +30s but it only reset the time to 00:30seconds.

```
child: RaisedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                             if (controller.isAnimating)
                                controller.duration = Duration(seconds: 30);
                            },
                            color: Colors.white,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30),
                            ),
                            textColor: Colors.black,
                            child: Text("Give player +30s ")),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Solution using an `AnimationController` combined with a `Timer`. I used an initial time of 10 seconds and a time increase of 5 seconds for a faster demo.

[image]

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Timer Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool done = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: done
            ? Text('TIME OUT')
            : CountDownTimer(
                onCompleted: () => setState(() => done = true),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CountDownTimer extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback onCompleted;

  const CountDownTimer({
    Key key,
    this.onCompleted,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CountDownTimerState createState() => _CountDownTimerState();
}

class _CountDownTimerState extends State<CountDownTimer>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Timer _timer;
  int _elapsed;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // AnimationController
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: kInitialTime);
    _controller.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
    _controller.addStatusListener(
      (AnimationStatus status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          _timer.cancel();
          widget.onCompleted();
        }
      },
    );
    // Elapsed Counter
    _elapsed = 0;
    _timer = Timer.periodic(
      Duration(seconds: 1),
      (_) => setState(() => _elapsed++),
    );
    // Launch the Controller
    _controller.forward();
  }

  void increaseTime([int extraTime = kExtraTime]) {
    _controller.duration =
        Duration(seconds: _controller.duration.inSeconds + extraTime);
    _controller.reset();
    _controller.forward(from: _elapsed / _controller.duration.inSeconds);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        CircularProgressIndicator(
          value: _controller.value,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black12,
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 12.0),
        Text('$_elapsed / ${_controller.duration.inSeconds}'),
        const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => increaseTime(),
          child: Text('MORE TIME'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

// CONFIGURATION

const Duration kInitialTime = Duration(seconds: 10);
const int kExtraTime = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the duration to 30 seconds, what you need to do instead is add to the remaining duration. You can probably use the `+` operator of the Duration class: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Duration/operator_plus.html

Something like this:

```dart
onPressed: () {
  if (controller.isAnimating) {
    controller.duration += Duration(seconds: 30);
  }
},
```

Not sure if the controller actually supports this.

Comment: Maybe add a controller.forward() afterwards

Comment: I added controller forward and it's reversing the timer , plus when I click next question , the times starts like from 2:00 , not 1:00 anymore